# Show text only for specific user in php

Tags: php

I am trying out simple PHP page. I am trying out the following:

```
<?php
include("db/db_config.php");
session_start();
$user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];

$ses_sql = mysqli_query($bd, "SELECT username FROM cmn_users where username='$user_check'");

$row=mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql);

$login_session=$row['username']; //get session username

echo ("<p style='text-align:left;'><h1>HEADER WILL COME UP <span style='float:right;'><a href='/admin.php'>ADMIN</a> | <a href='/logout.php'>Logout</a></h1></span></p>");

?>
```

I want to show admin page (link) only for a particular user. Like admin should be hidden near loggout if admin user doesn't login...How do I do it?

I have got session's userID but I don't know how control the text in php/html.

Help on this will be great.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? I'm only seeing an echo with a bunch of inline HTML...

Comment: Well, how do you know if someone is an admin?  How would you construct that `if` statement?  What happens when you *try* to construct that `if` statement?

Comment: @Fyntasia: As I said I have got session's userid and admin control or not details. I want to know the way to use IF statement with html. How do I do it?

Comment: @David: I have sessions userid and flag to say if the user is admin my question is how do I use it on IF condition in HTML. I know how to control the page in PHP but I don't how to hide ahref link for particular user.

Comment: Well, let's see your full PHP file then.
We don't know or can't see how you generate your content. Let alone help you with splitting it up.

Comment: @SanjanaNair: Are you just asking how to make an `if` statement?  How to access session data?  Something else?  We don't know the specifics of how you're implementing your website, so we can't know the *exact keystrokes* you need for your code.  But basically you need to use an `if` statement to check whether your user is an admin and only output the link if that's true.  If you're not familiar with what an `if` statement is then you should *really* be starting with some PHP tutorials.

Comment: @Fyntasia added what everything that is on my php file.

Comment: @David: I know what IF statement . How do I implement that on HTML. If session userId is this then show admin or else hide it. How do i do this part?

Comment: @SanjanaNair: This has nothing to do with HTML.  You're writing PHP code.  The semantics of what you just stated are your exact code.  `if ($_SESSION['username'] == 'admin') { // output the admin stuff }`  (Or however you determine if the user is an admin)

Comment: check my answer, you need to strore in different variables

Comment: have just edited my answer, plz check

Comment: Great.. Thanks a lot... and @David. Both codes are working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to store html links in your variables, and use them where needed, like this,

```
<?php
include("db/db_config.php");
session_start();
$user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];

$ses_sql = mysqli_query($bd, "SELECT username FROM cmn_users where username='$user_check'");

$row=mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql);
$login_session=$row['username']; //get session username
$adminLink = " <a href='/admin.php'>ADMIN</a> | ";
$logoutLink = " <a href='/logout.php'>Logout</a>";
?>
```

// suppose your html header link container

```
<div>
    <p style='text-align:left;'><h1>HEADER WILL COME UP <span style='float:right;'><?php echo $adminLink.$logoutLink ?>
    </h1></span></p>
</div>
```

============================================

for blocking acces on admin page

```
<?php
// start session
session_start();
// check if username is admin

replace it with your admin user name

$adminUsername = "admin";
if($_SESSION['login_user'] !== $adminUsername){
    // isn't admin, redirect them to a different page
    header("Location: /someotherpage.php");
}

?>
```

Comment: But the admin page will just show up for all users. I want to show admin page only for particular user.

Comment: so, what you mean is to  block access of admin page for other users? also can you dump your session and show here?

Comment: can you upvothe answer if it helpful for you?

Comment: I already did it. Some one had made downvote - I upvote it already.

Answer (score 2):

> If session userId is this then show admin

The semantics of your statement are your exact code:

```
if ($_SESSION['username'] == 'admin') {
    // output the admin stuff
}
```

(Or however you check if the user is an admin.  Based on username, some identifier, something else, etc.  Your question doesn't specify.)

So you'd output whatever is before the admin link, then conditionally output the admin link, then output whatever is after it.  Something like this:

```
echo "<p style='text-align:left;'><h1>HEADER WILL COME UP <span style='float:right;'>";
if ($_SESSION['username'] == 'admin') {
    echo "<a href='/admin.php'>ADMIN</a> | ";
}
echo "<a href='/logout.php'>Logout</a></h1></span></p>";
```

There are many other ways you can structure it as well.  Perhaps store the resulting links in variables and conditionally concatenate them as needed, then `echo` the result of that only once at the end.

But the concept is the same however you do it.  If the user is an admin, output the admin link.  That way if the user is not an admin, they never see that link.

**Note:** The admin page *itself* must also implement security.  There is nothing to stop a user from *guessing* the link and trying to open that page.  Do not consider the approach in your question to be security.  This is nothing more than user experience.